# Dynamic flex box with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to create a layout like this example below

1. Parent container have fixed height
2. If just have one child list, the list takes all height of container
3. If have two lists, each list takes enough space for its content. Any list with height > container height - the other list height will show scroll, in case the other list has height > 50% of parent then 2 lists will take 50% height of parent and show scroll

I have tried using flexbox but still have not found any solution

[image: example]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

.list1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.list2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.list1 div,
.list2 div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list1">
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list2">
    <div>
      item1
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t make sense of this: “ Any list with height > container height - the other list height will show scroll”. If say the first list has height greater than the container height how much of it is shown and where does the second list start?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Let me know if this is what you mean.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

.list1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50%;
}

.list2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 50%;
}

.list1 div,
.list2 div {
  padding: 20px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list1">
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
    <div>
      item1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list2">
    <div>
      item1
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, in this case, i want the second list shrinks its height to its content height, instead of always taking 50% of the parent's height

Comment: So in that case you can either use max-height of 50% so that if you add additional items on it it will only take the max 50% of the given height of teh container. Hope this is what you mean look at sample above then see if that make sense.